# How to fully uninstall pip installed with easy_install?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

On Windows 7, I install pip with easy_install and want to install a lower version of pip.
I want to remove the old version, but have no idea how to completely remove the pip installed by easy_install (or if there is a way to do it without going through easy_install, that is fine). How do I do this?

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Ironically, `pip` is intended to replace `easy_install` to a large extent to enable consistent package update and uninstall...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no completely automatic uninstall but you can do it in two steps:

```
easy_install -m pip
```

This should remove pip from `easy-install.pth` and print the full path to where pip is installed. Now just manually remove the path that the previous command printed. Or you could just manually edit `easy-install.pth` and remove the pip sources if you know where they are located.

Comment: What files should I delete? Where would all the easy_install pip files be located? Is it really just the pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg file referenced in it?

Comment: Just the .egg file or folder.

Comment: Actually I realized that if the package that was installed includes user scripts, like I believe pip does, then those would still be left behind by the above. In case of pip there is probably a file called `pip` in the same location where easy_install is. This doesn't really matter if you install another version of pip because the other version's install will overwrite the scripts anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I found that the following command worked.

It deleted the installed files and the `.egg` directory.
It also provided a confirmation prompt.

> `pip uninstall pip`

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36819110/3066295).

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall pip in windows:

- Run command prompt as administrator
- Give the command `easy_install -m pip`
- This may not uninstall pip completely. So again give this command `pip uninstall pip` If by previous command pip got uninstalled then this command wont run, else it will completely remove pip
- Now check by giving command `pip --version` This should give pip is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove PIP in windows directly type this command**

> rmdir /s /q C:\Users\prans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

Comment: Does this remove pip, or _Python?_