# unable to uninstall pip macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Tags: python, bash, macos, pip

I've installed `pip` using `sudo easy_install pip` command. I've also checked that it was installed using `which pip` command.

However, I'm not able to uninstall it now as it was advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247889/how-to-cleanly-remove-pip-that-is-installed-by-using-easy-install) using `sudo pip uninstall pip` command

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.1.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing
```

So, I've tried to solve this problem using a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682332/how-to-install-pip-in-python-2-7-on-macos-big-sur), however I'm still getting this error.

Can someone help me to remove it, please?

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip uninstall pip` result in the same error? If so can you try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053391/12128336.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the location `/usr/local/bin` and delete following files:

- `pip`
- `pip2`
- `pip2.7`
- Any other file with a prefix `pip`.

If you get permission error for any file e.g. `pip2`, change the permission using root user as `chmod +x pip2`.

Now, go to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and delete all packages with prefix `pip`. Also delete from `Library/Python/3/`, if you've installed in python3 too.